# Load hive partitioned table to Spark Dataframe

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using `Spark 1.4.1` version. I am trying to load a partitioned Hive table in to a DataFrame where in the Hive table is partitioned by the `year_week` number, at a scenario I might have 104 partitions.

But I could see the DataFrame is getting loaded with the data into 200 partitions and I understand that it is due to the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` set to 200 by default.

I would like to know if there is any good way I can load my Hive table to Spark Dataframe with 104 partitions with making sure that the Dataframe is partitioned by `year_week` number during the Dataframe load time itself.

The reason for my expectation is that I will be doing few joins with huge volume tables, where all are partitioned by `year_week` number. So having the Dataframe partitioned by `year_week` number and loaded accordingly will save me a lot of time from re-partitioning them with `year_week` number.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `df.repartition($"year_week")`?

Comment: yes, I am able to do. But the repartition causes data shuffle, which is costlier in my case. So I try see a way to load the Dataframe with the same partitions of the Hive table during the  load time itself. I try to get this to avoid the repartition on Dataframe. Is there any partitioning strategy that I can initialize with the Dataframe?

Comment: I see now. Nothing I know about. We ended up with loading every partition as a separate DataFrame, repartitioning and simply uniting frames later. This way we somehow limited repartitioning to a single worker.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hiveContext.sql("Select * from tableName where pt='2012.07.28.10'")`

Where, pt= partitionKey, in your case will be year_week
and corresponding value with it.